# Android build time is too long due to more tables in realm database.

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, build-time

Whenever i run the app, it took more time to build in android. i am using realm database. it have more than 300 tables. when i remove the realm table files, it building normally. For offline purpose, we are using this much tables. my app have only realm files and one activity. how to solve this issue. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Realm needs to do byte code manipulating of your RealmObject classes which may takes time. There is a issue track it https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3034 . How much time does the build take with/without RealmObject?

Comment: 25 to 30 min with 350 realm objects. 3 to 4 min with 23 realm objects.